# How to make pop up window movable?

Tags: javascript

I created pop-up window, opening in the same page but it is neither movable nor resizable.

My code:

```
$(function(){
var overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');
$('.close').click(function(){
$('.popup').hide();
overlay.appendTo(document.body).remove();
return false;
});

$('.x').click(function(){
$('.popup').hide();
overlay.appendTo(document.body).remove();
return false;
}); 

$('.click').click(function(){
overlay.show();
overlay.appendTo(document.body);
$('.popup').show();
return false;
});
});
```

Comment: How are you attempting to move it? In the code above you only add the popup to the document after clicking a button.

Comment: Yes After clicking the button only the pop up will open and i want to move the pop up wherever i move my cursor

Comment: Have you attempted this at all?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)  to create the pop-up window.

Comment: If u want the OP to try out something, then it has to go as a comment.